# python module ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have an application installed in a virtual environment (venv). When I attempt to run the application

```
$ venv/bin/python purge
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "purge", line 2, in <module>
    import datamanip
ImportError: No module named datamanip
```

module: datamanip is located in `gate/venv/ext/datamanip/datamanip`.
The datamanip directory contains `__init__.py`.

The script is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import datamanip
from lib import lib

def purge():
    lib.init()
    with lib.get_db() as db:
        db.purge()
        db.execute( lib.sql[ "schema" ] )
        lib.deploy( db )
    datamanip.file.wipe_dir( "work/log" )

purge()
```

If I change line 2 to: "from ext import datamanip", the script succeeds until the next module is not found (again, located in /venv/ext). (For example, datamanip itself calls modules located in /ext so it is the next fail point)

The same holds true for every module that is called from venv/ext.

sys.path is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.path)
    ['', '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/user/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

I've tried the same without a virtual environment and have exactly the same issue. Thanks for any help/guidance in advance.

Comment: How and why is your module getting located in `venv/ext`? If you were installing it the typical way (letting `setuptools` or `distutils` do the work for you), it would be under `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Agreed. I inherited this application with zero documentation  so am stuck sorting how it works before making changes.

Comment: As I understand it, though, it *doesn't* currently work -- isn't that why there's a question to be asked?